# Outlook VSTO Addin Application Item Send Event Order

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I have 2 Outlook VSTO Addin Applications which are called App1 and App2. I have defined Application ItemSend event for these applications that can be seen there

App1 :

```
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Application.ItemSend += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(Application_ItemSend);
    }
    void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("App1");
    }
```

App2 :

```
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Application.ItemSend += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(Application_ItemSend);
    }
    void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("App2");
    }
```

When I run both Addins and click mail send button, the shown MessageBox order is : App2 -> App1

Then for only App1, I defined this.Application.ItemSend inside a task.

Changed only App1 :

```
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
        { 
            this.Application.ItemSend += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(Application_ItemSend); 
        });
      
    }
    void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("App1");
    }
```

In this scenario, shown MessageBox order is :  App1 -> App2

After that, I have added another MessageBox at the end of ThisAddIn_Startup for App1 such that :

```
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
        { 
            this.Application.ItemSend += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(Application_ItemSend); 
        });
        MessageBox.Show("Dummy");
    }
    void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("App1");
    }
```

This time the shown MessageBox order after clicking send button : App2 -> App1

This seemed interesting to me. What is the relation between threads, messagebox, and itemsend event order? Do I have any control of prioritizing ItemSend events across addins?

Actually I have to write multiple Addins for Outlook and somehow I need to control which Addin's onItemsend event should be fired before.

By the way, when I delete MessageBox.Show("Dummy") and replace it with Thread.Sleep(5000), App1 is shown first which confused my mind further :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should not depend on add-ins receiving event notifications in any particular order. Each add-in should handle the event on its own without any reliance or dependency on the other add-ins.

Microsoft does not specify the order that add-ins are loaded or the order in which events are fired. While there is a pattern to it, it is not something that your add-in should depend on.

Answer (score 0):

Besides not depending on any particular event order, you should never use OOM on a secondary thread, such `Task.Factory.StartNew`.